# How to open Microsoft Word by function call?

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I want to accomplish a few tasks:

1. Open a Word document through my
   program in C# and create a document
   path to read or write to.
2. Change the formatting of text in the Word document as if I wanted the Word window to give me the text in RTF format or plain text or docx (supported formats)
3. Retrieve the text in my given format such as RTF from the Word window as the user closes the Word window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These 2 links will help you.

http://nishantrana.wordpress.com/2007/11/03/creating-word-document-using-c/

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mgold/CreatingandOpeningMicrosoftDocumentfrom.NETUsingCSharp11262005050939AM/CreatingandOpeningMicrosoftDocumentfrom.NETUsingCSharp.aspx